# How can I check if a resource inside Kubernetes has been deleted for some reason?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, amazon-eks

I am a junior developer currently running a service in a Kubernetes environment.

How can I check if a resource inside Kubernetes has been deleted for some reason?

As a simple example, if a deployment is deleted, I want to know which user deleted it.

Could you please tell me which log to look at.

And I would like to know how to collect these logs.

I don't have much experience yet, so I'm asking for help.
Also, if you have a reference or link, please share it. It will be very helpful to me.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Start with [enabling audit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) with lots of [online resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=kubernetes+audit+log+example&rlz=1C1GCEU_enMY949MY949&oq=kubernetes+audit+log&aqs=chrome.2.69i59j0i512l9.4319j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on AWS and using EKS I would suggest enabling "Amazon EKS control plane logging" By enabling it you can enable audit and diagnostic logs streaming in AWS cloudwatch logs, which are more easily accessible, and useful for audit and compliance requirements. Control plane logs make it easy for you to secure and run your clusters and make the entire system more audiatable.

As per AWS documentation:

```
Kubernetes API server component logs (api) – Your cluster's API server is the control plane component that exposes the Kubernetes API. For more information, see kube-apiserver in the Kubernetes documentation.

Audit (audit) – Kubernetes audit logs provide a record of the individual users, administrators, or system components that have affected your cluster. For more information, see Auditing in the Kubernetes documentation.

Authenticator (authenticator) – Authenticator logs are unique to Amazon EKS. These logs represent the control plane component that Amazon EKS uses for Kubernetes Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) authentication using IAM credentials. For more information, see Cluster authentication.

Controller manager (controllerManager) – The controller manager manages the core control loops that are shipped with Kubernetes. For more information, see kube-controller-manager in the Kubernetes documentation.

Scheduler (scheduler) – The scheduler component manages when and where to run pods in your cluster. For more information, see kube-scheduler in the Kubernetes documentation.
```

Reference:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html